determinantal ideal of sum of Galois conjugate matrices
Given $n$ matrices $A_i \in \mathbb{Z}^{m\times m}$. I am interested in the ideal $I_d(A)$ generated by the $d\times d$-minors of $A = \sum_{i=1}^n x_iA_i \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots , x_n]$.
The matrix $A$ has the following properties:

The rank of the matrix is always at least $d$, for any choice of $(x_1, \dots , x_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$.
The rank is precisely $d$, for some $a = (a_1, \dots , a_n) \in \mathbb{K}^n$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$. Furthermore, $\langle \sigma(a) \mid \sigma \in \text{Gal}(\mathbb{K}) \rangle = \mathbb{K}^n$.

In particular, if we pick $\sigma_i(a)$ ($1\leq i\leq n$) to be generators of $\mathbb{K}^n$, and if we define new variables via
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1(a)^T\\ \vdots \\ \sigma_n(a)^T\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\ \vdots \\ y_n\end{pmatrix},$$
then we can rewrite $A = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \sigma_i(M)$ with $M = \sum_{i=1}^n a_iA_i$.
Since all $y_i\sigma_i(M)$ have rank $d$, we see that $I_d(y_i\sigma_i(M)) = (y_i^d)$, i.e. the full ideal of all homogeneous polynomials in one variable.
Does it hold that $I_d(A)$ is the full ideal of all homogeneous polynomials in $d$ variables (be it $x_1$ to $x_n$ or $y_1$ to $y_n$)?
Or more specifically, does $(\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(\mu)y_i)^d$ lie in $I_d(A)$ for some $\mu \in \mathbb{K}$?
This question seems to be linked with Rank of sum of Galois conjugates of a matrix. But as far as I can tell, it only says that if some $d\times d$-minor of $M$ is non-zero, then we can find $(y_1, \dots ,y_n)\in \mathbb{K}^n$ such that the same minor of $A$ is non-zero.
